# Can't write into other partitions after installing Kubuntu 16.10

Tags: linux, windows-10, partitioning, kubuntu, read-only

I have Windows 10 64-bit installed on my system. Then I installed Kubuntu 16.10 into another partition, and everything was successful. But the problem is it seems that I can't modify or add new data into any of the other partitions, including the Windows partition. I can only write data into Kubuntu partition which is ext4. All of the other partitions are NTFS.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is checking if ntfs-3g package is installed. You would need this to read/write to ntfs drives. Just try the following in konsole:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

If you get a reply stating that `ntfs-3g is already the newest version` you have them installed already, otherwise the tools would be installed.
If this doesn't help, you should provide some more information: How do you access your Windows partition? How did you try to write to it? What error messages do you get?

Comment: yes i get ntfs-3g is already the newest version. i open dolphin and only my kubuntu disk is mounted. when i click on other disks, they get mounted. i can read any of them normally. but i cant write to them. even simple copy-paste is not working. i cant see paste enabled, and if i try to delete something, it also seems locked. why is that? whats wrong with my system?

Comment: if you click on the disks in the sidepanel in dolphin, they get mounted read-only. You would have to change permissions to let your user write to it. For trying, just open the disk in dolphin as you did, then notice the path it shows you on top of the window. Should be "/media/USER/weird-code-of-numbers-and-letters". Open up a konsole window and type 'sudo chown USER:USER /media/USER/weird-code-of-numbers-and-letters'. Change "USER" and "weird-code-of-numbers-and-letters" to what your dolphin-path looks like. Now, you should be able to write a file in the root folder of that drive.

Comment: For a permanent solution, you will have to add the drive to your fstab and mount it to a directory of your choice.